# Debug Maven project in Eclipse with third party sources

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven, m2eclipse

I am currently developing a maven project in eclipse. The m2eclipse plugin works beautifully. It even works out of the box with debugging.

But when I am debugging open source third party libarries. It seems maven could automatically pull the source code down, but the eclipse debugger cannot resolve the currently execution point to the correct source file location.

I am sure the source code is downloaded because I can look at it and set break point. And the break point works.

But eclipse shows the source code and the currently execution point in too different windows. An example would be "TransformerImpl.class" tab window shows the source code, but the current execution point in shown in another tab window with header "Transformer.transform(Source,boolean)Line:642". This windows shows no source code.

I am felling there is some simple configuration that I am missing that could make this work. Then it will be really beautiful.

Comment: I think it works now in Eclipse. They probably fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a bug introduced in one of the last m2eclipse versions. So, the workaround is to click on "Edit Source Attachment" button in the editor opened for a missing class and manually attach the source jar from  the Maven local repository where it is downloaded by m2eclipse.

You should actually [report this issue to m2eclipse](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE), so developers can fix it in the future versions.

Comment: Thanks! I was hitting my head trying to figure out what's going on. Glad to know it is a bug. Will try to file a bug report on this.